# Creating an array of structs defined in another header file

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have the following file structure

```
service.h
config.h
config.c
```

In the `service.h` file a `struct serviceStruct` is declared with one member a `unsigned int.`

I declare an `array of serviceStructs` in the file `config.h` and in the `config.c` file, I initialize the members.

Now I get the error `array type has incomplete element type`

How can i solve this error?

---

[update from comment:]

service.h:

```
typedef uint32_t board_spi_select_id_t;

struct spi_device
{ //! Board specific select id 
  board_spi_select_id_t id;
};
```

config.h:

```
#include "service.h" 

#define SPI_SLAVE_COUNT 4 
#define SPI_SS_ADF4350_C1 0 
#define SPI_SS_ADF4350_C2 99 
#define SPI_SS_AD9854_C1 3 
#define SPI_SS_AD9854_C2 99 

struct spi_device ssid[SPI_SLAVE_CNT];
```

config.c:

```
#include "config.h" 

struct spi_device ssid[SPI_SLAVE_CNT] =
{
  { SPI_SS_ADF4350_C1 },
  { SPI_SS_ADF4350_C2 },
  { SPI_SS_AD9854_C1 },
  { SPI_SS_AD9854_C2 } 
};
```

Comment: Please show a bit more context; pehaps an `include` is missing somewhere?

Comment: show us the declaration of array of `struct serviceStructs` in the file `config.h`

Comment: the struct declaration in the service.h

    typedef uint32_t board_spi_select_id_t;
    
    struct spi_device {
     //! Board specific select id
     board_spi_select_id_t id;
    };
the config.h file

    #include "service.h
    #define SPI_SLAVE_COUNT 4
    #define SPI_SS_ADF4350_C1  0  
    #define SPI_SS_ADF4350_C2  99 
    #define SPI_SS_AD9854_C1  3  
    #define SPI_SS_AD9854_C2  99 
    struct spi_device ssid[SPI_SLAVE_CNT];

the config.c file

    #include config.h
    spi_device_t spi_ss_id[4] = {{SPI_SS_ADF4350_C1}, {SPI_SS_ADF4350_C2},{ SPI_SS_AD9854_C1},{SPI_SS_AD9854_C2}};

Comment: Cant post is as an answer no reputation

Comment: What compiler are you using? Your posted source compiles fine for me if I change `SPI_SLAVE_CNT` to `SPI_SLAVE_COUNT`

Comment: Do not significantly change your question after answers had been posted, as  those edits might make certain answers un-understandable. Just add more to your answer without deleting what there was.

Answer (score 2):

In `config.c`

```
spi_device_t
```

is unknown.

Either use `struct sp_device` instead of `spi_device_t`

```
struct spi_device spi_ss_id[4] =  
{
  ...
```

or declare the latter, for example by adding

```
typedef struct spi_device spe_device_t;
```

at the end of `service.h`.

Comment: So include `service.h` in `config.h` (and not in the main program).

Comment: @Jongware That's what the OP seems to be doing.

Comment: Ah, you're right -- I got lost in the order of includes and defines. `spi_device_t` is simply not defined *anywhere*. gcc reports `error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'board_spi_select_id_t'`

Comment: @alk Sorry, it was copied wrong, I used both methods you described but without succes. The error array type has incomplete element type hits on the line where i define the the array in my header file. 

I edited the original post.

When i declare the the array only in the config.c file it compiles without error. So i dont think its an include problem

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `SPI_SLAVE_COUNT`, but in the array definition you use `SPI_SLAVE_CNT` - notice the different spelling.

If I change this, it compiles fine for me with both gcc and clang.